# How to write regex expression error on symbol ( and )

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to replace ":)" with  using this code :

```
txt = txt.replace(':)','<img title=":)" src="resource/images/smiles/smile.png" style="'+style+'">');
```

but if the symbol is more than one, this code cant handle this. I try to using regex like this :

```
txt = txt.replace(/:)/g,'<img title=":)" src="resource/images/smiles/smile.png" style="'+style+'">');
```

but this code is error, How to write a right regex expression in this case?

Comment: Escape the parenthesis with a backslash. `/:\)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
you have to meaningless some escape character from regular expression like

```
) = \)
```

Your code become

```
var pat = /:\)/g;
var str = '<img title=":)" src="resource/images/smiles/smile.png" style="'+style+'">';
txt = txt.replace(pat,str);
```

Answer (score 0):

brackets are special characters in regular expressions, you will need to escape that when putting it in between the double slashes. it should be:

```
/:\)/g
```

instead of

```
/:)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `(`, it has special meaning for a regex:

```
txt = txt.replace(/:\)/g,'<img title=":)" src="resource/images/smiles/smile.png" style="'+style+'">');
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use escapse ), just like 

`var txt = ':)abcd:)';
var style = '';
txt = txt.replace(/:\)/g,'<img title=":)" src="resource/images/smiles/smile.png" style="'+style+'">');
console.log(txt);`